# Grab multiple numbers 1-10 from string

Tags: javascript, regex, matching

I am parsing a string of multiple numbers between 1 and 10 with the eventual goal of adding them to a set.

There will be multiple concatenated numbers after a text identifier such as `{text}12345678910`.

I am currently using `match(/\d/g)` to grab the numbers but it separates `1` and `0` in `10`. I then look for `0` in my String Array, see if there's a `1` in the element before it, turn it into a `10` and delete the other entry. Not very elegant.

How can I clean up my matching code? I definitely don't need to use regex for this, but it makes grabbing the numbers fairly easy.

Comment: There're no "bonus questions" in SO terminology :) You could either search for it or ask another question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just match with this regex:

```
/10|\d/g
```

(*instead* of the one you use currently, not additionally)

Regex is executed left-to-right, so first it finds any occurrences of 10, and then of other digits (so using, for example `/\d|10/g` or even `/\d|(10)/g` won't work either).

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you :)